# How to hide terminal when not needed?

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer, vim8

In VScode ,we are using `ctrl+j` to hide the terminal. Then if we press ctrl+j again, it will open the same terminal.

Is it possible in VIM/NEOVIM? I tried `:Terminal` ,but there is no straightforward way to toggle it. I have seen some plugins are there to do. Is there any shortcut to hide the terminal when not needed?

Comment: Relevant [todo item](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/32e5ec0b017adb68fe36adb9a9a362abdaffe7f4/runtime/doc/todo.txt#L169) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/lacygoill/0bfef0a2e70ac7015aaee56a670c124b).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 (not in Gvim): Use `CTRL-Z` to suspend Vim. That will give you Vim's parent shell.
To go back to Vim, enter `fg` in the command line.

Option 2: Spawn a terminal in a Vim window with `:ter` (or `:terminal`). Now, go back to the original
window with `CTRL-W CTRL-W` and press `CTRL-W _` to maximize its height. Note that the terminal
window will still occupy one line. To get back the terminal window, you can use `CTRL-W =` to restore both windows to half of the screen, and then `CTRL-W CTRL-W` to move focus to the terminal again. You will want to read `:help window-resize`.

Comment: You can also close the terminal and re-open it, but you have to re-open by buffer number, which is not terribly intuitive (at least to me)

Answer (score 2):

You could open the terminal in a new tab page (`:tab terminal`) and then use `:tabnext` / `:tabprevious` to switch between them.